# include_blank in form select_option not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I am trying to include a default blank first option in a select field as follow:

```
= f.select :role, options_for_select(User::ROLE), {}, include_blank: true, class: "form-control"
```

which is not giving the expected outcome.

`User::ROLE` is an array in the User class as follow:

```
ROLE = ["user", "doctor", "manager"]
```

How can I make the select option in the field to return a blank option for first select, without having to include a blank option as first element of my `ROLE` array? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below should fix it:

```
= f.select :role, options_for_select(User::ROLE), { include_blank: true} , { class: "form-control" }
```

Here is the method signature:

[`select(object, method, choices = nil, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block) public`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Comment: Oh thanks, @Rakshit  this fixed it.
and one more thing, the blank option returns an empty string. is there a way I can make it return `nil`? thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [**API**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select),it should be

```
= f.select :role, options_for_select(User::ROLE),{include_blank: true}, {class: "form-control" }
```